# Loop em R para achar o maior valor em uma coluna

Tags: r

Gostaria de uma ajuda no código abaixo. Possuo no objeto `df_ar` uma coluna chamada `litros_cerveja`, com o consumo da bebida no países da América do Sul no ano de 2010. Gostaria de salvar no objeto `menor_cerveja` o menor consumo presente nessa coluna, juntamente com o país, presenta em coluna com esse nome.

```
for (i in nrow(df_arl$litros_cerveja)){
    if (df_ar$litros_cerveja[i] < df_ar$litros_cerveja[i - 1]){
      menor_cerveja <- data.frame(df_ar$pais[i], df_ar$litros_cerveja[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem que ser `for(i in 2:nrow(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar da [resposta do Willian Vieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/402102/loop-em-r-para-achar-o-maior-valor-em-uma-coluna/402125#402125) estar, num certo sentido, correta, é preciso notar que talvez não seja a solução para todos os casos.

A função `which.min` (e a correspondente `which.max`) retorna o *primeiro* valor do mínimo do vetor (respetivamente, do máximo do vetor). Se houver mais que um mínimo então, para obter *todos*, deverá ser de outro modo.

```
x <- c(3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 4)

which.min(x)
#[1] 2
x[which.min(x)]
#[1] 1

which(x == min(x))
#[1] 2 5
x[which(x == min(x))]
#[1] 1 1
```

Ora, na pergunta pede-se

> Gostaria de salvar no objeto `menor_cerveja` o menor consumo presente nessa coluna, juntamente com o país, presenta em coluna com esse nome.

Nada garante que exista só um país com o menor consumo de cerveja. Eu diria que muito provavelmente não há empates mas quem sabe? No caso fictício que se segue há dois países com o mesmo menor consumo de cerveja.

```
df_ar <- data.frame(pais = letters[1:6], 
                    litros_cerveja = c(3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 4))

i <- which.min(x)
df_ar[i, ]
#  pais litros_cerveja
#2    b              1

j <- which(x == min(x))
df_ar[j, ]
#  pais litros_cerveja
#2    b              1
#5    e              1
```

Comment: então a função which(x == min(x)) utiliza valor lógico. Caso TRUE, j <- which(x == min(x))... certo?

Comment: @vinifrm `x == min(x)` compara cada valor de `x` com `min(x)` e retorna valores lógicos. Depois, `which` transforma os valores lógicos em índices numéricos. Por exemplo, tente `which(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))`. O `which` deve ser usado quando há a possibilidade de haver `NA`s nos dados, indexar com `which(c(TRUE, FALSE, NA, TRUE))` é seguro mas com `c(TRUE, FALSE, NA, TRUE)` não é.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa criar a função para encontrar o menor valor, elas já existem:

```
min() # para retornar o menor valor
which.min() # para retornar a posição do menor valor
```

no seu caso seria algo assim:

```
pos <- which.min(df_ar[, 'litros_cerveja']) # retornar posição do menor valor
menor_cerveja <- df_ar[pos, c('pais', 'litros_cerveja')]
```

Comment: obrigado meu amigo. Não conhecia a função which.min().